# why is my webapplication NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/reflect/AjTypeSystem

Tags: java, weblogic, aspectj, noclassdeffounderror, spring-aop

I´ve a maven web application. I´m using JSF, Primefaces, Hibernate, Spring, Spring AOP and ORACLE 11g.
So when I deploy my application on Glassfish 3 it works perfectly, but when I deploy it on weblogic 12 I get the next error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'Usuarios' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/reflect/AjTypeSystem

Caused By: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/lang/reflect/AjTypeSystem
```

So I opened my war then I looked in WEB-INF/lib and I found (aspectjrt.jar and aspectweaver.jar), so I´m not sure what´s wrong.
Here is the part of my pom where I declare the aspectJ libs:

```
<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

    <spring.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <aspectj.version>1.7.0</aspectj.version>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <netbeans.hint.deploy.server>WebLogic9</netbeans.hint.deploy.server>
    <netbeans.hint.j2eeVersion>1.6</netbeans.hint.j2eeVersion>
</properties>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency> 

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>      
    <!-- aspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

So does anyone knows what´s happening. I already googled the error but every one says that the aspectjrt.jar and aspectweaver.jar might be missing, but I´m pretty sure they aren´t.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973970/how-to-solve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror)?

Comment: yes, the jars are being loaded into the war and it compiles fine with maven. So when I deploy it in glassfish it works, but it doesn´t work in weblogic 12 for some reason it resist´s to recognize my weaver and aspect jar that are inside the compiled war.

Comment: Maybe a settings problem?

Comment: Is there another `Caused By` after that `Caused By`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this in weblogic.xml :

```
<container-descriptor>
   <prefer-web-inf-classes>true</prefer-web-inf-classes>
</container-descriptor>
```

and this in weblogic-application.xml :

```
   <prefer-application-packages>
      <package-name>org.springframework.*</package-name>
   </prefer-application-packages>
```

I haven't tried this myself, but found this on http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/aop/91846-can-t-find-ajtypesystem-during-deployment .. basically what's going is that even that you have aspectjrt.jar and aspectweaver.jar in your WAR, they don't get loaded because WLS thinks they are available somewhere else in its system classpath ("higher up" in the classloader hierarchy typically), sometimes with another version.  This is a typical problem on EE application servers, and each one of them (WLS, WAS, JBoss) has some configuration to influence class path loading order. If above doesn't exactly work, Google that further, and you'll figure it out... best of luck.

Comment: it´s a web app so I only have the weblogic.xml so after adding the container description I get: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContex nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: weblogic.xml.jaxp.RegistryDocumentBuilderFactory cannot be cast to javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.

Comment: Have you researched this new error? It's seems to be fairly common... see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925901/classcastexception-while-parsing-xml-with-weblogic.  The solutions I've spotted seem to fall into two categories: 1. either you exclude certain XML JARs from your WAR - try e.g. an (possible several) <exclude> of xml-apis:xml-apis in your pom.xml.  Maybe you'll need to exclude more.  2. Use of <prefer-application-packages>... her you would have to wrap your WAR into an EAR, just for that.  I'd try road 1. first.

Comment: it worked I just added a couple of exclusions thanks.